# android studio generate bundle failed - File 'root/lib/macosArm64/libmultik_jni-macosArm64.dylib' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PackageBundleTask$BundleToolWorkAction
   > File 'root/lib/macosArm64/libmultik_jni-macosArm64.dylib' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.
```

This is the error I get when I try to generate the signed bundle.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These libraries caused the problem, I don't need them, so I just deleted them from the build.gradle:

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:multik-core:0.2.0"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:multik-default:0.2.0"